# @SpringBootTest with WireMock fails in GitLab CI pipeline but passes locally

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, wiremock

The following is a simplified version of a `@SpringBootTest` which spins up a RabbitMQ container using Testcontainers.

The basic workflow to be tested is:

1. Send a message to the target queue.
2. Reject the message so that it gets moved to the corresponding dead letter queue.
3. Check that the message is present in the dead letter queue.
4. Check that a request was made to the RocketChat WireMock.

```java
@RegisterExtension
protected static WireMockExtension rocketChatWireMock = WireMockExtension.newInstance()
        .options(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort())
        .build();

@DynamicPropertySource
static void configureRocketChatProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("rocket-chat-url", () -> rocketChatWireMock.baseUrl());
}

@Test
void shouldSendAlertToRocketChat() throws JSONException {
    final int retryCount = 3;
    final String payload = buildPayload();

    rocketChatWireMock.stubFor(post(anyUrl()).willReturn(ok()));

    sendMessage("my-routing-key", payload, retryCount);
    waitUntilMessageIsPresent("my-queue");
    rejectMessage("my-queue");
    waitUntilMessageIsPresent("parking-lot-queue");

    final Message parkingLotMessage = rabbitTemplate.receive("parking-lot-queue");
    assertThat(parkingLotMessage).isNotNull();

    await().untilAsserted(() -> rocketChatWireMock.verify(postRequestedFor(anyUrl())));
}
```

This test works fine when started on my computer, but it always fails when running in a GitLab CI pipeline with a GitLab runner with the following message:

```
Caused by: com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: 
Expected at least one request matching: {
  "method" : "POST"
}
```

Comment: At what point is the HTTP Post request should be made?  Once a message is received from a queue or?  

This could be a timing thing, as it is probablly running faster on your local machine vs on the ci.  

Or a Springboot Context thing, try @DirtiesContext

Comment: The HTTP request is made directly after the message was delivered to the parking lot queue. I also guess that it might be a timing issue but haven't been able to track it down yet.

Comment: Add logs to verify all your steps are working as they should.  When it comes to JMS, there is always delays to be expected.

I suggest you add a pollDelay to your  .await()
    .pollDelay(4, TimeUnit.MINUTES), to wait until it assert.